# Connect Pentaho Data Integration with Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse

Tags: jdbc, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm starting with this database, up to now i get works the following cases:

- Connect using Sql developer and import data from a csv
- Connect by JDBC into a Java file

The problem now is that I need Pentaho DI connect with Oracle Autonomous dataWarehouse

Does any body knows how to do it? Maybe using JDBC connections?

Comment: I would assume that JDBC is yet the only way to go until pentaho and the rest have created their own connector. Kind of how it works for talend: https://cloud.oracle.com/opc/paas/datasheets/Talend-Connection-ADW.pdf